# How to split string in blackberry cascades

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-cascades

1. I have a json array data like `{"RegistrationResult":"Registered Success:Empid:157:TableName:COMPANY156"}`
2. Now how i want split the string and show the list view in qml like the follwing

   Registered Success

   Empid = 157

   TableName = COMPANY156
3. Please tell the concept to **split a string** and **show the result in qml**

I can get result for the follwing method: `{"RegistrationResult":["Registered Success","Empid":"157","TableName":"COMPANY156"]}`

But i dont know how to split the string.. Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got solution by referring documentaion

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qstring.html#details

**STEP 1:** 
Declare this in **cpp** header  `#include <QStringList>`

**STEP 2:**

```
JsonDataAccess jda;
        QVariantMap map = jda.loadFromBuffer(reply->readAll()).toMap();

        QVariantList addresses = map["RegistrationResult"].toList();

        qDebug() << "RegistrationResult is "<<map["RegistrationResult"].toString();


        QString result;
        QString empid;
        QString empid_no;
        QString companyname;
        QString::SectionFlag flag = QString::SectionSkipEmpty;

        result=m_temperature.section(':', 0, 0);
        empid=m_temperature.section(':', 1, 1);
        empid_no=m_temperature.section(':', 2, 2);
        companyname==m_temperature.section(':', 4, 4);
```

Comment: Will this approach fail if the results come back in a different order?  JSON does not specify an order does it?

Comment: Am mentioned this is solution for only which am posted above query.. This will not applicable for all methods..